# ipython notebook and ginput

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create an interactive plot in ipython notebook.  I am attempting to run the sample code from matplotlib's website as below.

```
t = arange(10)
plot(t, sin(t))
print("Please click")
x = ginput(3)
print("clicked",x)
show()
```

I get this error:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in start_event_loop(self, timeout)
2370         This is implemented only for backends with GUIs.
2371         """
-> 2372         raise NotImplementedError
2373 
2374     def stop_event_loop(self):

NotImplementedError:
```

I assume this has something to do with running ipython notebook and HTML.  Is this possible to fix? and how?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you started the ipython notebook using:

```
ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

You don't need the `show()` function call. Plots will be automatically shown. The `show()` function is needed only when you use one of the `qt`, `wx`, `gtk`... backends.

Also, the `ginput()` function is not available in the `inline` mode. If you need it, you should start the notebook using some other backend that you have installed. For example `qt` or `tk`:

```
ipython notebook --pylab=qt
ipython notebook --pylab=tk
```

Comment: Yes,  The error is generated before that line at x = ginput(3)

Comment: @jmerkow Oh sorry I missed that. `ginput` is also not available when you use the `inline` mode.

Comment: @jmerkow If you need these functions you should start the notebook with some other backend. Updated the answer.