# ginput Not implemented Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

In my project, I need to extract several points in pixel coordinate in order to transform those points to world points. So every time,  I'm using ginput function in Spyder (Python 2.7), I got the following error. An example of my code is given below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
os.chdir(r'My path')
rgb = io.imread('myphoto.jpg')
plt.figure(1)
pylab.imshow(rgb)
pylab.show()
[X,Y] = plt.ginput(5)
```

The error is as in below:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 592,
>   in ginput
>       return gcf().ginput(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line
>   1576, in ginput
>       show_clicks=show_clicks)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\blocking_input.py",
>   line 291, in **call**
>       BlockingInput.**call**(self, n=n, timeout=timeout)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\blocking_input.py",
>   line 114, in **call**
>       self.fig.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout=timeout)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py",
>   line 2364, in start_event_loop
>       raise NotImplementedError
>
> NotImplementedError

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spyder, but I think it uses ipython ? You get the same error in the ipython notebook, here's a related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839341/ipython-notebook-and-ginput

Comment: It looks like you're using a non-interactive backend (these days, mostly likely the IPython inline backend).  Try calling `plt.get_backend()` and see what it returns.  For most matplotlib functionality, you'll want an interactive backend such as `TkAgg`, `Qt4Agg`, `WxAgg`, `GtkAgg`, `nbagg`, `OSX`, etc.  You can switch backends in several ways, but for the most part, it needs to be done before `pyplot` is imported.  Use `matplotlib.use(backend_name)` or in IPython `%matplotlib backend_name` before importing `pyplot`.